# Can i give the percentage of rollout in ios appstore on submitting app for review?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

iam working on a small ios app,which has around 200 downloads/day.so even i set phased release on submitting review it will take 4 days to reach 10% users.it is a very long time and we couldn't detect possible crashes in short time.when i checked the documentation i couldn't find the option to set a custom percentage.
i reffered the official documentation https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/update-your-app/release-a-version-update-in-phases

is setting a rollout percentage is possible in ios appstore-connect?

Comment: No, you cannot customise the phased release